# Sharing create and update form in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm learning Laravel and have created a single form that is shared by the create and edit controller.

The create controller just returns the view.

```
 public function create()
    {
        return view('hotels.create');
    }
```

However i've had to put my edit controller and return it in an array

```
    return view('hotels.edit', [
       'hotel' => Hotel::with('hotelFacilities')->where('id', $id)->get()
    ]);
```

Now in my view I have to pass

```
$hotel[0]->hotelFacilities->fitness_centre
```

instead of

```
$hotel->hotelFacilities->fitness_centre
```

So now my create view is looking for `$hotel` where it is now `$hotel[0]` in the shared view. How can I change this so it's looking at the same reference to the $hotel variable?

Comment: `->get()` returns a collection, use `->first()` instead. (I think instead of `->where('id', $id)->first()` you could also just use `->find($id)`)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the same view for create and edit, you have to pass the same object for views. change code as below.

```
return view('hotels.create', [
   'hotel' => new Hotel
]);

return view('hotels.edit', [
   'hotel' => Hotel::with('hotelFacilities')->where('id', $id)->first()
]);
```